# Law of Trichotomy for Well-Orderings

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

Often in beginning set-theory courses, and in particular in Jech's book *Set Theory*, it is proved from scratch that given any two well-orderings, they are isomorphic or one is isomorphic to an initial segment of the other. This is the law of trichotomy for well-orderings, and while simple is not exactly trivial to prove. However, it is also proven in an apparently independent manner that every well-ordered set is isomorphic to an ordinal, and for any two ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ either $\alpha \subseteq \beta$ or $\beta \subseteq \alpha$. It is then trivially seen from this fact that that either $\alpha = \beta$ or $\alpha$ is an initial segment of $\beta$ or vice versa. From these facts about ordinals, the law of trichotomy for well-orderings follows immediately.

My question is: is there any reason to prove from scratch the law of trichotomy? Is it secretly used somewhere to prove some of these basics facts about ordinals, and I simply missed it? Or can this proof just be omitted?

Comment: The proof of Theorem 2.12 in Jech uses Corollary 2.6 and Lemma 2.7.  So I assume you only consider Theorem 2.8 redundant.  theorem 2.12 uses the axiom of replacement.  Theorem 2.8 holds in Zermelo's axiomatization without replacement.  The use of well-orders predates von-Neumann ordinals by several decades.  In $\mathsf{Z}$, ordinals are guaranteed to exist up to $<\omega\cdot 2$, but well-orders up to $<\omega_\omega$.